# Killer instinct cross plataform online?

Tags: pc, xbox-one, killer-instinct-2013

I want to know if I can play Killer Instinct in my PC against someone playing in a xbox one.

How does this work? Using xbox live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, there is no support for cross platform between Xbox and PC; At least, not for this title.

While there has been planned integration of multiplayer between Xbox One and PC for some time, now, no such feature is currently available.